# How to use apigateway for securing Java based REST APIs

Tags: java, authentication, aws-api-gateway

I am working on a project build in java that has android frontend. Its basically and android app that calls REST APIs build in java. I have created restful apis using springmvc, hibernate and eclipse. Currently I don't have any security mechanism for these apis (e.g. authentication tokens). I want to secure my APIs through AWS APIGATEWAY. I have done some research and have successfully implemented authentication through APIKeys. But according to document it's not that secure.
My understanding of this whole process is that Cognito user pool and Lambda authorizers will only be applicable in case of implementing REST APIS in apigateway but if i want to apply security on my already created backend APIs I'll have to use API KEYS. Can anyone tell me how I should go about it?

Comment: slm :) ........

Comment: provide ssl certificate for your domain

Comment: I have done that. It is https

Comment: Ssl grantees secure connection.and also as you mentioned you have api keys. There is completely secure .if you need more I can suggest you expire date time for keys.

Comment: And also what's the document you mentioned in your question which denied the security.